# How to solve this string literal error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This code below is giving me a unterminated string literal error, how can this be fixed?

below is javascript code (QandAtable.php).

```
$(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {

    var image_file_name = "<?php echo str_replace("\n", "", $image_file_name); ?>";

                  $('.upload_target').get(0).contentwindow
              $("iframe[name='upload_target']").attr("src", "javascript:'<html></html>'");

    jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php" + image_file_name)
        .done(function(data) {

        $(".imagemsg" + _cancelimagecounter).html(data);
    });

    return stopImageUpload();

});
```

below is imagecancel.php script where the ajax links to:

```
...

    $image_file_name = $_GET["fileImage"]["name"];

        echo "File Upload was Canceled";

            $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
            WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/". mysql_real_escape_string($image_file_name)."'";

        mysql_query($imagecancelsql);
```

In error console it is showing it as: `var image_file_name = "<br />`

Comment: Where is `$image_file_name` coming from? Have you tried echoing it to the page to verify that it contains the value it's supposed to contain?

Comment: Don't dump raw text into JS like that. at least do `echo json_encode(...)` to ensure you're generating syntactically valid JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, don't worry about the internal double quotes, it won't affect your javascript string

```
var image_file_name = "<?php echo str_replace("\n", "", $image_file_name); ?>";
```

Comment: What is the exact error now? Try using my new code, I've removed replacing "\n" with '\n' and changed it to "\n" to ""

Comment: updated code and question showing current line of code and what the error is showing now. It still hasn't worked, it is displaying same error.

Comment: What IS your image file name? Can you please view source and print the entire contents of the image file name variable?

Comment: @user1373827 can you do a `trim` on `$image_file_name` too. `var image_file_name = "<?php echo str_replace("\n", "", trim($image_file_name)); ?>";` just in case if there is any whitespace character causing the issue

Comment: I'm sure you won't want HTML in your image tag names either, so perhaps try this. var image_file_name = "<?php echo strip_tags(str_replace("\n", "", trim($image_file_name))); ?>";

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if I got your question correct, but there are few issues in your code.

when you are using $_GET, I guess you are doing it wrong `$_GET["fileImage"]["name"]` since its the GET parameter it will be simply `$_GET["fileImage"]`

But even before doing this, you should be sending it in the proper $_GET parameter i.e.

`jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php?fileImage=" + image_file_name)`